# How to pass singleton reference to an actor in thespian

Tags: python, singleton, actor

I would like pass a singleton reference to an actor in Thespian.
I'm using like ActorSystem the ActorSystem "multiprocTCPBase".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Good idea. Do let us know how you get on.

Comment: Thank you for response.
In fact, i would like to know how to do it. Do you know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Thespian (http://thespianpy.com) actors have an actor address that identifies them and can be passed to other actors in a message, allowing each actor to be created just once if you write your actor-based application that way.

In addition, the `createActor()` call has a `globalName` argument that can be used to identify a specifically named actor (http://thespianpy.com/using.html#sec-5-3).  This actor is a singleton for the system: any subsequent `createActor()` calls specifying the same `globalName` will return the original actor instead of creating a new actor (until the singleton dies, in which case a new singleton actor will be created on a subsequent call.

This singleton aspect of using the `globalName` is described, but that term is not specifically used; thank you for bringing this to my attention and I will update the documentation to add that to clarify the behavior.